# Enabling Windows defender to block USB Malware automatically

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, windows-defender

I want to turn on the Windows Defender Option preventing malware spreading from USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure autoplay is turned off for USB drives.

[How To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/236241/how-to-enable-disable-and-customize-autoplay-in-windows-10/)

2. Change a Windows Defender Setting and create a scheduled task to auto scan devices when they are plugged in.

[answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning/how-to-set-up-windows-defender-to-scan-removable/53d79e04-aa73-4852-980b-b805a5b44878)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 To Enable or Disable Scan Removable Drives during Full Scan in PowerShell**

1. Open an elevated PowerShell.
2. Enter the command below you want to use into PowerShell, and press Enter.

(Enable)
**Set-MpPreference -DisableRemovableDriveScanning 0**

OR

(Disable)
**Set-MpPreference -DisableRemovableDriveScanning 1**

3. When finished, you can close PowerShell if you like.

**Option 2 To Enable or Disable Scan Removable Drives during Full Scan using a registry key**

Locate the registry key as below and modify the DWORD value to 0 or 1.

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scan**

**DisableRemovableDriveScanning** DWORD

**0** or (delete) = enable scan
**1** = disable scan

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don’t want to scan USB sticks completely. I want the Defender to protect me from malicious software on the stick. That means the moment I put the stick on the PC and some software is „getting active“ defender should block it when it’s harmful. Or when I copy from stick to PC a certain file defender should stop copying when this file is harmful. 
I can summarize: I just put a USB stick in the PC and know I am safe.